# Worpress htaccess rewrite rule for single URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have a problem. We use Wordpress and we need to rewrite some URLs. Not all! It's just temporarily.

The basic htaccess looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

We now need a rewrite rule to simplify a long path:

/car/train/bike/human/tires/

should be:

/all-tires/

I thougt this will work, but sadly it doesn't.

```
RewriteRule /all-tires/$ /car/train/bike/human/tires/
```

We don't want to redirect (301), we just want to simplify a long path, so that the user just see's a short path in his address bar.

Can anybody help?

Thank you!
iPat

Comment: When configured in .htaccess context, the path segment RewriteRule matches against _never_ starts with a `/`, that has already been stripped off at that point.

Comment: (And of course the whole thing has to be placed _before_ the default WP routing.)

Comment: Hi @Cbroe, I don't really understand. I tried: to put the rewrite rule without starting / after RewriteEngine On. Doesn't work. Or how does it have to look?

Comment: That’s how it should look, basically. Add `[R=302]` at the end of the rule, and see if that forces an external redirect to that address then. If so, then the rule itself works - the rest of the problem might be with WordPress itself then.

Comment: Even a [302] doesn't change anything. Still won't work. When I take the same rule, same page, and use all-tires.php$ readme.html, it runs. I tried also /car/train/bike/human/tires/index.php, which works in the address bar, but not in the htaccess?

Comment: Explain what exactly “won’t work” means. Does the external redirect not happen?

Comment: I just get an 404 "Page not found".

Comment: With the browser address bar showing what?

Comment: Showing, the address: https://   mydomain.   com/ all-tires.html

Comment: Why are you trying to request `all-tires.html`, when we are talking about a rule that was supposed to match `all-tires/`? _What_ rule exactly are you testing now?

Comment: Sorry, I mixed it, always trying different variants. Same with all-tires/

Comment: Hi @CBroe do you have any more ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by CBroe you have to place it above the regular wordpress routing. Something like this, keep in mind this is a redirect not a rewrite.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Rewriterule all-tires/$ /car/train/bike/human/tires/ [QSA,L,R=302]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```